# Compare euclidean distances from different dimensions

Tags: euclidean-geometry, machine-learning, data-analysis

**EDIT:** I'd like to reformulate my primary question.

I have a set of points in $\mathbb{R}^D$ and I reduce the dimensions of the points to some $\mathbb{R}^L$. I do this with multiple configurations where I set the lower dimension size `L` to different values.

Say I lower the dimensions of the points `p` and `q` to $\mathbb{R}^2$ and  then to $\mathbb{R}^3$ and receive $p^{(2)}, q^{(2)}$ and $p^{(3)}, q^{(3)}$. Now I calculate the euclidean distance of $p^{(d)},q^{(d)} \: \:  \forall d \in \{2,3\}$ to get $d^{(2)}$ and $d^{(3)}$.

Are these distances comparable, or will $d^{(3)}$ generally be bigger than $d^{(2)}$?

**Background:**

I am using a supervised model to cluster data points. The goal is to have tight clusters. I would like to compare different models, but the problem is that they output the data points in different number of dimensions, like illustrated:

[image]

My metric to minimize is the sum of the distances between the points and the centroid of the cluster:

$$
\sum_{i}^{N}\sqrt{\sum_{j}^{D}(x_{ij} - centroid_j)^2}
$$

`D` is the number of dimensions and `N` the number of data points.

So my question is, how do I know which model is doing a better job in clustering the points?
I am pretty sure that I can't simply compare the metric mentioned above. How could I achieve this?

Comment: You can't. Depending on the projection to 2d, you can get different results if you try to plot 3d data set on a plane. And, obviously, sum of squares of distances will be large in 3d than 2d.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I already thought about that. How would you then approach this problem?

Comment: What do you mean by 'they output the data points in different dimensions'? I would have thought that a clustering model would take the data points as input and output a list detailing which data points belong to which cluster.

Comment: It isn't a classical clustering algorithm but a neural network encoder that can have different sizes of dense output layers.

Comment: How is the ground truth represented?

Comment: Is there a reason you wish to project onto the plane? This is valid of course, but is less obvious than just using the metric on $\mathbb{R}^n$ when you have $n$ variables. Perhaps you wish to emphasize some aspect of your data?

Comment: I don't know if my question is too vague but I am not getting an answer on my primary question. My question is if two euclidean distances are comparable if calculated on vectors from different dimensions.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen I don't want to project onto a plane. I simply have 1) points in u dimensions and 2) points in v dimensions where u > v. If I now calculate a distance for points a and b for 1) can I compare this distance to the metric of a and b in 2)

Comment: Why don't you want to project onto a plane? It could solve your problem. Project the $3D$ version into $2D$ space, compute the metrics, and now you're comparing apples to apples.

Comment: You still did not explain how you reduce the dimension of points. Do you just mean the orthogonal projection? Then yes, the distance decreases.

Comment: To decide "if two euclidean distances are comparable if calculated on vectors from different dimensions" depends on _how_ the points in the domain are mapped to the points in the codomain. If that's just what your black-box algorithm does then I think the answer is "no, they are not comparable". If you [edit] the question to tell us just how that mapping works maybe we can help. (Clarify with an [edit], not in a comment.)

Comment: @AdrianKeister that is exactly what I am doing right know using PCA. But by that I lose information and that introduces noise

Comment: @EthanBolker I can't go too much into detail, because it is not open sourced. But basically, there is a neural network that outputs a dense layer each for one of two inputs and the loss is the euclidean distance between the two outputs.

Comment: That's not enough information for me to help, If you edit the question to provide that material perhaps someone else can. If you can,  post one or two nontrivial but not huge examples showing input and output.